# How to replace a regex by given values in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of regular expressions like

```
$regex = "{Hello ([a-zA-Z]+), you are ([0-9]{2}) years old today\.}u"
```

Is there a function to do something like the following :

```
$result = function_i_am_looking($regex, "John", 25);
echo $result; // Outputs : "Hello John, you are 25 years old today."
```

Note: this is not some kind of templating engine I'm building ;)

Note 2: I can't predict what regex will be and in what order.

Comment: [preg_replace is the command, doc linked](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) Your `$regex` isn't valid PRCE Regex though.

Comment: The closest thing is `sprintf` for writing strings from a format, but that's not the same thing as a regex

Comment: @t3chguy Where is it wrong ?

Comment: @hek2mgl : I was thinking about replacing each parenthesis with the paramters given, in specific order.

Comment: the `{` and `}` should be `/` for a start... But I think `sprintf` is what you need in this case.

Comment: @CyrilN. It will be only possible as long as you add the restriction: "no nested matching groups"

Comment: I think this is a X->Y problem. I'm not at all sure this is what you want. FOr starters: your regexp looks like some sort of template, not a regexp (there is an unescaped `.` in there for one, and you are using it as a template). Further, your resultsentence doesn't match your regex. This isn't very surprising, as you are suggesting to just replace the parts in `()` with the string, but nevertheless: `John` isn't lowercase. I'd say that you might want to explain what you are trying to do in more bigger-picture, why you thing you need a regexp as a template, etc.

Comment: @t3chguy `{}` are allowed for regex in PHP (in fact, any non alphanumerical characters ;)

Comment: @Nanne : I fixed the errors in my regex. Regarding the example, I tried to make it simpler because it would have been too long to explain otherwise. I think it's clear enough right now. I'm looking to make it work both way. In one way, I have preg_match_all that is working correctly, now I'm looking to have the other way around work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the restriction that matching groups aren't nested in the regex patterns, you can use this:

```
$regex = "/Hello ([a-z]+), you are ([0-9]{2}) years old today./u";

$replacements=array("John", 25);
$result = preg_replace_callback('/\((.*?)\)/', function($m) use (&$replacements) {
        return array_shift($replacements);
}, $regex);

echo $result; // Outputs : "Hello John, you are 25 years old today."
```

IMO this is already the best - generic - thing you can do. However, while it works (a bit :) ), I don't think it is a good idea to do so. What you want is a template engine, or even printf (yes, you want that ;) )

Comment: `printf`, like `sprintf` are interesting, but I cannot make them work the other way around (matching something like "Hello hek2mgl, you are 37 years old today.") ... except if I change the original preg_replace by replacing "%s" by "(\w+)", etc

Comment: Like the anonymous function too ;)

Comment: @CyrilN. Don't expect too much from that solution. I can only say that you are not the first person searching for a way to use a regex as a) parser b) format specifier. I think to remember a project written in C. let me try to find it again for you ...

Comment: @CyrilN. Check this http://blog.dotnetwiki.org/CommentView,guid,ebbeae3f-9e53-4f67-9d30-6d8a1d2c4903.aspx ... It is not exactly the same as you want, but if you need you might settle on this or at least their ideas. There are also related projects, stress your google. Good luck!

Comment: Nice, this is interesting! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You maybe want to use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
sprintf("Hello %s, you are %d years old today.", "John", 25);
```

would print:

```
Hello John, you are 25 years old today.
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I already have the regex in use, I can't change it to a `sprintf` accepted format :/

Comment: EXCEPT if you can make the other way around work, suppose you have multiple sentences in an array, including the one in the example, and I give you the text `"Hello Wumm, you are 14 years old today."`, will you be able to match it to `"Hello %s, you are %i years old today."` ?

Comment: @CyrilN. No, I don't see any way to do this. (using sprintf format specifiers)

Answer (score 0):

you can use some mixed substring for replacing them

```
$your_string = "Hello @##@YOUR_NAME@##@, you are @##@YOUR_AGE@##@ years old today.";

$new_string = get_full_string($your_string, "John", 25);

echo $new_string;

function get_full_string($str, $name, $age)
{
     $str = str_replace("@##@YOUR_NAME@##@", $name, $str);
     $str = str_replace("@##@YOUR_AGE@##@", $age, $str);
     return $str;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://eval.in/176691)**

**METHOD : 2**

```
$your_string = "Hello ([a-z]+), you are ([0-9]{2}) years old today.";

$new_string = get_full_string($your_string, "John", 25);

echo $new_string;

function get_full_string($str, $name, $age)
{
     $str = str_replace("([a-z]+)", $name, $str);
     $str = str_replace("([0-9]{2})", $age, $str);
     return $str;
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/176703)**

Comment: Thanks but the regex system is already in place, I can't change it, except if you can make it work both ways (take a look at the comments I made to @wumm answer)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I may have missed a point : I can't predict the regex structure (which parameters and in what order).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$regex = "{Hello ([a-z]+), you are ([0-9]{2}) years old today.}u";
$result = function_i_am_looking($regex, "John", 25);
echo $result; 

function function_i_am_looking($reg, $str, $num) {
    $reg = preg_replace('/\(\[a-z\].*?\)/', '%s', $reg);
    $reg = preg_replace('/\(\[0-9\].*?\)/', '%d', $reg);
    return sprintf($reg, $str, $num);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I may have missed a point : I can't predict the regex structure (which parameters and in what order).